# Parse unstructured flat file on SSIS

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis, script-task, flatfilesource

I have a problem parsing the unstructured text file. I tried to upload everything into one column with data type DT_STR but it throws error since there are special characters like '=' in my file. I tried with DT_TEXT data type, it worked well. But I cannot perform any operations on the column. I need to remove empty rows in that column which can be done with 'conditional split'. But the condition:

```
[column 0]!=""
```

does not work and throws the following error:

### TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio

Error at Data Flow Task [Conditional Split [32]]: The data types "DT_TEXT" and "DT_WSTR" are incompatible for binary operator "!=". The operand types could not be implicitly cast into compatible types for the operation. To perform this operation, one or both operands need to be explicitly cast with a cast operator.

Error at Data Flow Task [Conditional Split [32]]: Attempt to set the result type of binary operation "[Column 0] != """ failed with error code 0xC0047080.

Error at Data Flow Task [Conditional Split [32]]: Computing the expression "[Column 0]!=""" failed with error code 0xC0047084. The expression may have errors, such as divide by zero, that cannot be detected at parse time, or there may be an out-of-memory error.

Error at Data Flow Task [Conditional Split [32]]: The expression "[Column 0]!=""" on "Conditional Split.Outputs[Case 1]" is not valid.

Error at Data Flow Task [Conditional Split [32]]: Failed to set property "Expression" on "Conditional Split.Outputs[Case 1]".

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0204006 (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap)

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

I did the parsing with c# script previously. But now I need to avoid coding. Any ideas on how to parse this file are appreciated. Thankyou

Comment: The equals sign is not going to be a special character

Comment: Then I have no idea on why it is not taking the entire data as string. The error shows up in line 4 when I give it as string. Line 4 has only equals signs

Answer (score 1):

Let's break this down

> The data types "DT_TEXT" and "DT_WSTR" are incompatible for binary operator "!="

You have an expression `[column 0]!=""` the empty string `""` is DT_WSTR and `[column 0]` is DT_TEXT data type. As the error message indicates, you cannot test for a not equals condition between these types.

I would look at either converting Column 0 to DT_WSTR or simply checking the length. `LEN([column 0]) > 0`

### The SSIS way

The bigger issue is that your file is *not* "unstructured text file". It's very structured. The column headers are in line 3 (1 based counting) and data starts in 5. The data itself looks fixed width from here.

How do you handle that in SSIS? Create a Flat File Connection Manager of type Ragged Right. Indicate there are no header columns and skip the first 4 rows/data starts in row 5. Create the columns by specifying the width and now your data flow is simpler and the package will run faster.

Comment: LEN([column0]) > 0 looks fine but it does not work. The error is: [Conditional Split [2]] Error: The expression "LEN([Column 0]) > 0" on "Conditional Split.Outputs[Remove blank rows]" evaluated to NULL, but the "Conditional Split" requires a Boolean results. Modify the error row disposition on the output to treat this result as False (Ignore Failure) or to redirect this row to the error output (Redirect Row).  The expression results must be Boolean for a Conditional Split.  A NULL expression result is an error.

Comment: Also, I need data from first row, not from 4. I need name of STN and date as well.

Comment: I tried with DT_WSTR. It shows the same error as with DT_STR. The error I posted in my question says that '!=' does not work with data types DT_TEXT and DT_WSTR. It does not mean that it works with DT_WSTR data type.

Comment: I agree with that the solution is to configure your source properly. If you need the name and STN then create a second connection with only those 2 columns to extract those values. For your conditional split use = 0 instead and switch your splits.

Comment: I have managed to import the file using ragged right and specified inputcolumnwidth for each column in the advanced properties of flat file connection manager. Ragged right automatically removed empty rows. That way I separated all the columns. I have added STN and Date using derived column with substring expression. Couldn't find a better way to do than this.